# 301 redirects not working properly. Numbers in URL being ignored

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have just replaced my old non-Wordpress site with a Wordpress site. Now I need to redirect approximately 400 old URLs to their equivalent pages on the new site.

I have already recorded all the old urls and new urls, but when I put the code in the .htaccess file I am getting a strange result.
If I try to redirect to any url that has a number in it, the redirect tries to redirect to that url minus the numbers.

For example:

```
Redirect 301 /international_organizations/africaamerica_institute http://nyintl.net/international-organizations-in-new-york/2792/africa-america-institute/
```

Redirects to http://nyintl.net/international-organizations-in-new-york/africa-america-institute/
Which isn't actually a page and thus returns a 404 error.

Anyone have any idea what's going wrong? All my posts on the new site have the month/year syntax in the url, so this means that 95% of my redirects aren't working.
All the urls that don't contain numbers are redirecting perfectly.

I have made sure to put all my redirects ABOVE the WP rewrite rules, but that hasn't made a difference (tried them below as well).

Comment: checked if you have any OTHER rewrites occuring? There's nothing in your `Redirect` that'd tell apache to strip out any component of the url.

Comment: Other than 301 redirects, the only other lines in the htaccess file are ones put in by WordPress. 
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: I did figure this out this morning. It works if I change to a rewrite instead of a redirect.

This is what I used that worked: 

`RewriteRule ^page\/working_in_nyc$ "http\:\/\/nyintl\.net\/work\-in\-new\-york\-101\-working\-in\-new\-york\-city\/" [R=301,L]`

I still haven't figured out why some of my redirects were working while ones containing numbers weren't working. But I'm not going to look further into it now that I have a solution.